# strpos fail to find text in string

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
if(strpos("Italia (16)", "Italia"))
    {
        echo "done";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "fail";
    }
```

I want check if in the first string `Italia (16)` there is the text `Italia` but I get: `fail` when I should get `done` 'cause the text is available in the first string. Why happean this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must check for `===false`

```
if(strpos("Italia (16)", "Italia")!==false)
{
    echo "done";
}
else
{
    echo "fail";
}
```